# Bash Script - Running current or new instance of an application

Tags: linux, bash, shortcut

I added a shortcut to an application in ubuntu. Each time i press shortcut keys, a new instance of application is created. I need only one instance, what script i can use to open the existing instance of application or creates a new one if the application is not running?

Comment: Look to see if it is already running and optionally hit Alt+Tab?

Comment: The application I use is a simple dictionary in system tray and does not appear in Alt+Tab. I use it quite often, so i press the shortcut key many times during reading articles so i want it to open up very fast just with pressing the shortcut key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends greatly on the application. The most trivial case would be the known process name which can only be run by you (that is, no stray instances on the system):

```
pidof applicaton || /usr/bin/application
```

Opening an existing application may get tricky and, again, depends on the application. I'd suggest that you take a look at [alltray](http://alltray.trausch.us/) thingie and pay special attention to the `alltray --help` output.

**Edit by ypnos:**
If you want to restrict this to the current user only, you should use pgrep instead of pidof, like this:

```
pgrep -u `id -u` application || application
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try a script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
user=`id -un`
lock=/tmp/$user-$1-lock
if [ -e $lock ]; then
    exit #app is already running
fi

touch $lock
$@
rm $lock
```

If you called the script 'runner.sh', you can use it like this:

```
runner.sh xcalc
```

Is for cases where pidof doesn't work. Else go for hacker's solution, which is also more robust.

Comment: As much as i understand your script it ensures that only one instance of application can be running system wide even if there are many users logged on and using the same application?

Comment: No, the lock file is bound to the user, see the variable $user in the script.